# Which one is the primary and secondary side of this Transformer

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, charger, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

I found it on a old laptop charging adapter. I what to  know the primary and secondary side of this transformer. 
It has total 8 pins. Each side has 4 pins

[image: This transformer]

Comment: Measure the resistance of each winding - that should give you a hint.

Comment: @solar_mike it has 8 pins. if it has 4 pins with 2 pins each side I can easily measure the resistance. but with 8 pins how can i do this. Please answer this with details. Thanks

Comment: If you found it on an old laptop charger, then, if you still have it, the case may give you an input and output voltage(s).

Comment: Any winding on a transformer can be the primary so you question is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can tell by looking at the diameter of the wire wrapped around the posts on the bobbin. The primary or primaries will have thinner wire than the secondaries.

Do note that you have a ferrite-core transformer that is designed to be used in a switching power supply at many kHz and that it won't respond pleasantly at all if you apply anything like mains voltage to it at 50 or 60 Hz (smoke, noxious fumes, blown fuses etc.)

Comment: I'm also facing problem with its connection.  It has 8 pins. how can I give input and take output. Can you please help me with any circuit diagram?

Comment: You can find many schematics on line for switching power supplies. Most in chargers are flyback types. Check out [Power Integrations](https://www.power.com/) website for some based on their proprietary chips, but a notebook charger may be based on a different chip or more generic controller chips.